# PostgreSQL - Bad value for type int: t

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to perform a select from a view and I am getting this error:

```
 Bad value for type int : t
```

I have checked the types of everythng and they match up. alarm_id is of type int8 and the id is a long.
This is the code that executes the query.

```
sql = "select * from alarm_view where alarm_id = ? "
try (PreparedStatement ps = super.prepareStatement_(sql)) {
        ps.setLong(1, id);
        try (ResultSet res = ps.executeQuery()) {
            if (res.next()) {
                alarm = alarmHelper.makeAlarmFromResultSet(res);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the  `prepareStatement_` method do ?

Comment: it's basically the same as `connection.prepareStatement`

Comment: `t` is the text representation of `true` in postgres. Looks like you're trying to map a boolean field to an integer somewhere. BTW, there is no line number with your error?

Comment: the error line is the exception that is not included in this but it's just `throw new Exception(e)`

Comment: That error is thrown by `ResultSet.getInt()`. The code you posted doesn't call it, so presumably it's somewhere inside your `alarmHelper`. What does the stack trace say?

Comment: Yeah the error was in the place you said, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that the type of variable `id` on this line:

```
ps.setLong(1, id);
```

is actually `String` and not a long/integer number.  Post more code around where this variable is defined - it may be clearer from there.

Comment: the id variable is an argument to this function, and its type is Long